# Count over 2 dimensions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using `excel 365`.

I want to get aggregated for each product how often it is used by the departments.

[image]

I tried `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$E$18;$I$2)` on the times, however I do not know how to get the products?

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what would be the expected return in `I3`, would that be 7? If so > `SUMPRODCUCT(($A$2:$A$18=$H3)*($B$2:$E$18=I$2))`

Comment: Create a pivot table, Product column as rows, department as column, and timeframe as count of (value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is truly complicated. My solution made it even more complicated, since it accounts for the number of departments (assuming that's the only data in the entirety of row 1) and products (assuming that's the only data in the entirety of column A) and any number of data introduced, also assuming the fixed placement of your calculations as shown in the example picture. Here's the formula you need in I3:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("R"&MATCH($H3,$A:$A,0)&"C2",0):INDIRECT("R"&LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA($A:$A)+1)=$H3),SEQUENCE(COUNTA($A:$A),1,2))&"C"&COUNTA($1:$1)+1,0),I$2)
```

You need to drag it all over the calculation area. I wanted to do a single cell spill array formula, but I don't think it's even possible right now due to its limitations (it generates the array first, and spills afterwards, making it static).